# WSO2 IS 5.3.0 - Can the admin user of a tenant be locked out/disabled?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

The features described in this doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/User+Account+Locking+and+Account+Disabling are around locking accounts after too many failed login attempts and disabling accounts after idle activity.

Let's say the user in question has the "admin" role (as usually configured in a tenant). Can they get their account locked/disabled? If so, how does one get out of this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, admin users can get locked out after exceeding the maximum number of login attempts as same as other users. The user will have to wait until the end of the configured account unlock time window to retry.

```
Account unlock timeout = Configured Account Unlock Time * (Lock Timeout Increment Factor ^ failed login attempt cycles)
```

An alternative approach available to unlock an account as explained in [[1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Locking+a+Specific+User+Account)]. In this case, a different admin user can login and unlock the locked user account.